# How to know the total no: of rows in our SQL query result if it is greater than 1 million in Azure databricks notebook?

Tags: sql, azure, statistics, azure-databricks

I am trying to query a huge data set and I am able to download only 1 million rows worth of data. I want to know how much data there is, as a part of the query result.

Comment: Assuming your data is in a dataframe, `<dataframe>.count`

Comment: What format of your huge data set is? A csv file in Azure Blob Storage or others like `parquet` format?

Comment: it is in csv format .  I already have a query statement for pulling the data. so how to know the size ie no: of rows and columns of the data that is being pulled  in sql?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your DataFrame / query is under `df` variable:

```
df.count()
```

will give you the number of rows and

```
len(df.columns)
```

will give you number of columns.
You can further explore the schema of the data with `df.printSchema()`

1 million rows is generally not that many and while the job has to be run to count all of them it shouldn't be any problem.

Comment: also i asked this because the max size of file is 1 million rows when we download

Comment: Neeraj, just to be clear - creating a query with dataframe api, e.g. ``` df = spark.read.csv('').filter('..').groupby('..')``` doesn't run the query - it's just a defintion of a transformation. Running ```df.collect()```, ```df.count()``` or writing to another file / db are all actions and run whole parallel processing. 1 million rows is very little quite honestly, I wouldn't worry about loading it unless there are thousands of columns.

Answer (score 0):

There are three solutions to realize your needs, as my sample code below.

1. To mount your container of Azure Blob Storage to Azure Databrick Filesystem, please follow the section [`Mount Azure Blob Storage containers to DBFS`](https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/spark/latest/data-sources/azure/azure-storage.html#mount-azure-blob-storage-containers-to-dbfs) of the offical document `Data Sources > Azure Blob Storage`. And here is my sample code below.

   ```
   storage_account_name='<your storage account name>'
   storage_account_access_key='<your storage account key>'
   container_name = '<your container name>'

   dbutils.fs.mount(
     source = "wasbs://"+container_name+"@"+storage_account_name+".blob.core.windows.net",
     mount_point = "/mnt/<a mount directory name under /mnt, such as `test`>",
     extra_configs = {"fs.azure.account.key."+storage_account_name+".blob.core.windows.net":storage_account_access_key})

   df = spark.read.csv('/mnt/<your mount directory name under /mnt, such as `test`>/df.csv')
   lines_num = df.count()
   columns_num = len(df.columns)
   print(lines_num , columns_num )
   ```
2. To directly access the csv file from Azure Blob Storage, please follow the other section [`Access Azure Blob Storage directly`](https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/spark/latest/data-sources/azure/azure-storage.html#access-azure-blob-storage-directly) of the offical document `Data Sources > Azure Blob Storage`. And here is my sample code below.

   ```
   storage_account_name='<your storage account name>'
   storage_account_access_key='<your storage account key>'
   container_name = '<your container name>'

   spark.conf.set(
       "fs.azure.account.key."+storage_account_name+".blob.core.windows.net",
       storage_account_access_key)
   blob_name = '<your csv blob name>'
   url = "wasbs://"+container_name+"@"+storage_account_name+".blob.core.windows.net/"+blob_name

   df = spark.read.csv(url)
   lines_num = df.count()
   columns_num = len(df.columns)
   print(lines_num , columns_num )
   ```

The two solutions above as @Daniel said is using the Spark DataFrame functions to do it. For a huge data set, it will may cost huge memory in the cluster servers of Azure Databricks. So you can consider for my next solution.

3. To count the stream of http response body of the csv blob url with SAS token by Azure Storage SDK for Python. First, you need to install the package `azure-storage` in the cluster of Azure Databricks.

   [image]

   [image]

   My sample code as below.

   ```
   from azure.storage.blob.baseblobservice import BaseBlobService
   from azure.storage.blob import BlobPermissions
   from datetime import datetime, timedelta

   account_name = '<your account name>'
   account_key = '<your account key>'
   container_name = '<your container name>'
   blob_name = '<your blob name>'

   blob_service = BaseBlobService(
       account_name=account_name,
       account_key=account_key
   )

   sas_token = blob_service.generate_blob_shared_access_signature(container_name, blob_name, permission=BlobPermissions.READ, expiry=datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=1))
   blob_url_with_sas = blob_service.make_blob_url(container_name, blob_name, sas_token=sas_token)

   import urllib.request

   resp =urllib.request.urlopen(blob_url_with_sas)

   is_first = True
   lines_num, columns_num = 0, 0
   for line in resp:
       if is_first:
           columns_num = len(line.split(b','))
           is_first = False
       lines_num += 1
   print(lines_num , columns_num)
   ```

Comment: Thank you !!  i will try this out ! But my guess is that will any specific sql query will help in this ?

Comment: I  cannot add libraries because i dont have permissions in the clusters